# Better way to sum a property value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype-programming

I have something like this:

```
$scope.traveler = [
            {  description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
            {  description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
            {  description: 'Adult', Amount: 75},
            {  description: 'Child', Amount: 35},
            {  description: 'Infant', Amount: 25 },
];
```

Now to have a total Amount of this array I'm doing something like this:

```
$scope.totalAmount = function(){
       var total = 0;
       for (var i = 0; i < $scope.traveler.length; i++) {
              total = total + $scope.traveler[i].Amount;
            }
       return total;
}
```

It's easy when is only one array, but I have others arrays with a different property name that I would like to sum.

I would be happier If I could do something like this:

```
$scope.traveler.Sum({ Amount });
```

But I don't know how to go through this in a way that I could reuse it in the future like this:

```
$scope.someArray.Sum({ someProperty });
```

Comment: The reduce method is perfect for this. Here is a great [explainer](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-finally-understand-reduce).

Comment: ***TL;dr :***   `myArray.map(i=>i.myProperty).reduce((a,b)=>a+b);`

Answer (score 197, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Due to all the downsides of adding a function to the Array prototype, I am updating this answer to provide an alternative that keeps the syntax similar to the syntax originally requested in the question.

```
class TravellerCollection extends Array {
    sum(key) {
        return this.reduce((a, b) => a + (b[key] || 0), 0);
    }
}
const traveler = new TravellerCollection(...[
    {  description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
    {  description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
    {  description: 'Adult', Amount: 75},
    {  description: 'Child', Amount: 35},
    {  description: 'Infant', Amount: 25 },
]);

console.log(traveler.sum('Amount')); //~> 235
```

**Original Answer**

Since it is an array you could add a function to the Array prototype.

```
traveler = [
    {  description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
    {  description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
    {  description: 'Adult', Amount: 75},
    {  description: 'Child', Amount: 35},
    {  description: 'Infant', Amount: 25 },
];

Array.prototype.sum = function (prop) {
    var total = 0
    for ( var i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++ ) {
        total += this[i][prop]
    }
    return total
}

console.log(traveler.sum("Amount"))
```

The Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9BAmj/

Comment: thanks @sp00m now I have changed my implementation with array.reduce just like gruff-bunny answered.

Comment: You may need to polyfill the reduce function if you need to support older browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Please don't extend `Array.prototype` as it might break your code in the future. [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice).

Comment: @bottens what if there is a null object in the array?

Answer (score 315):

I know that this question has an accepted answer but I thought I'd chip in with an alternative which uses [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), seeing that summing an array is the canonical example for reduce:

```
$scope.sum = function(items, prop){
    return items.reduce( function(a, b){
        return a + b[prop];
    }, 0);
};

$scope.travelerTotal = $scope.sum($scope.traveler, 'Amount');
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/4cFU3/)</kbd>

Comment: brilliant answer, is it possible to put `$scope.travelerTotal = $scope.sum($scope.traveler, 'Amount');` at the beginning of controller function ?

Comment: Yes if it comes after the sum function is created.

Comment: This can result in NaN, if the prop does not exist (undefined) in one of the objects in the array. I don't know if this is the best check, but it worked for my case: function(items, prop) {
            return items.reduce(function(a, b) {
                if (!isNaN(b[prop])) {
                    return a + b[prop];
                } else { return a }
            }, 0);
        }

Answer (score 251):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with destructuring to sum Amount:

```js
const traveler = [
  { description: 'Senior', Amount: 50 },
  { description: 'Senior', Amount: 50 },
  { description: 'Adult', Amount: 75 },
  { description: 'Child', Amount: 35 },
  { description: 'Infant', Amount: 25 },
];

console.log(traveler.reduce((n, {Amount}) => n + Amount, 0));
```

Comment: Simple and easy, my chosen answer

Comment: this should be the top answer

Comment: Simple and powerful approach - should have been the top of all answers. Thanks @patrick

Comment: Really great solution. I modified it a bit: (traveler.reduce((n, {Amount}) => n + Number(Amount), 0)

Comment: This finally made it clear how i can use reduce properly. Thanks

Answer (score 220):

> Just another take, this is what `native` JavaScript functions **`Map`** and **`Reduce`** were built for (Map and Reduce are powerhouses in many languages).

```
var traveler = [{description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
                {description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
                {description: 'Adult', Amount: 75},
                {description: 'Child', Amount: 35},
                {description: 'Infant', Amount: 25}];

function amount(item){
  return item.Amount;
}

function sum(prev, next){
  return prev + next;
}

traveler.map(amount).reduce(sum);
// => 235;

// or use arrow functions
traveler.map(item => item.Amount).reduce((prev, next) => prev + next);
```

> **Note**: by making separate smaller functions we get the ability to use them again.

```
// Example of reuse.
// Get only Amounts greater than 0;

// Also, while using Javascript, stick with camelCase.
// If you do decide to go against the standards, 
// then maintain your decision with all keys as in...

// { description: 'Senior', Amount: 50 }

// would be

// { Description: 'Senior', Amount: 50 };

var travelers = [{description: 'Senior', amount: 50},
                {description: 'Senior', amount: 50},
                {description: 'Adult', amount: 75},
                {description: 'Child', amount: 35},
                {description: 'Infant', amount: 0 }];

// Directly above Travelers array I changed "Amount" to "amount" to match standards.

function amount(item){
  return item.amount;
}

travelers.filter(amount);
// => [{description: 'Senior', amount: 50},
//     {description: 'Senior', amount: 50},
//     {description: 'Adult', amount: 75},
//     {description: 'Child', amount: 35}];
//     Does not include "Infant" as 0 is falsey.
```

Comment: `return Number(item.Amount);` to check for number only

Comment: I'd only argue with the name of the variable `prev` in the reduce function. To me, that implies that you're getting the previous value in the array. But really it's the reduction of all previous values. I like `accumulator`, `aggregator` or `sumSoFar` for clarity.

Comment: I do think this is the best anwser.

Comment: Note that the (arguable) advantages in separating the .map() and reduce() calls of having composable functions come at the cost of decreased performance because both `.map()` and `.reduce()` will separately iterate through the entire array. If you're processing large volumes of data, you would be better off using a single for-loop than separate array methods

Answer (score 142):

I always avoid changing prototype method and adding library so this is my solution:

Using reduce Array prototype method is sufficient

```
// + operator for casting to Number
items.reduce((a, b) => +a + +b.price, 0);
```

Comment: The second parameter (which determines the initial value of `a`) does the trick when using `reduce` with objects: in the first iteratorion, `a` won't be the first object of the `items` array, instead it will be `0`.

Comment: As a function:
`const sumBy = (items, prop) => items.reduce((a, b) => +a + +b[prop], 0);` 
Usage: `sumBy(traveler, 'Amount') // => 235`

Comment: As an old school programmer, the `reduce` syntax looks totally obtuse to me. My brain still "natively" understands this better: `let total = 0;
    items.forEach((item) => {
      total += item.price;
    });`

Comment: @AndrWeisR I like your solution best.  Also the use of native as it's such a buzz word that hardly gets explained what it's meant for. I made an even more basic line of code based on your solution and it worked great. `let total = 0; items.forEach(item => total += item.price)`

Comment: Thank you. this is best solution for my problem.

Answer (score 49):

Alternative for improved readability and using `Map` and `Reduce`:

```
const traveler = [
    {  description: 'Senior', amount: 50 },
    {  description: 'Senior', amount: 50 },
    {  description: 'Adult', amount: 75 },
    {  description: 'Child', amount: 35 },
    {  description: 'Infant', amount: 25 },
];

const sum = traveler
  .map(item => item.amount)
  .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
```

Re-useable function:

```
const calculateSum = (obj, field) => obj
  .map(items => items.attributes[field])
  .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
```

Comment: Perfect mate,  "+1"

Comment: Use reduce default value ```.reduce(*** => *** + ***, 0);``` others was missing that "+1"

Answer (score 26):

It's working for me in `TypeScript` and `JavaScript`:

```js
let lst = [
     { description:'Senior', price: 10},
     { description:'Adult', price: 20},
     { description:'Child', price: 30}
];
let sum = lst.map(o => o.price).reduce((a, c) => { return a + c });
console.log(sum);
```

I hope is useful.

Answer (score 23):

You can do the following:

```
$scope.traveler.map(o=>o.Amount).reduce((a,c)=>a+c);
```

Answer (score 22):

I thought I'd drop my two cents on this: this is one of those operations that should always be purely functional, not relying on any external variables. A few already gave a good answer, using `reduce` is the way to go here.

Since most of us can already afford to use ES2015 syntax, here's my proposition:

```
const sumValues = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, value) => acc + obj[value], 0);
```

We're making it an immutable function while we're at it. What `reduce` is doing here is simply this: 
Start with a value of `0` for the accumulator, and add the value of the current looped item to it.

Yay for functional programming and ES2015! :)

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure this has been mentioned yet. But there is a [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#sumBy) function for that. Snippet below where value is your attribute to sum is 'value'.

```
_.sumBy(objects, 'value');
_.sumBy(objects, function(o) { return o.value; });
```

Both will work.

Answer (score 6):

can also use [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
let totalAmount = 0;
$scope.traveler.forEach( data => totalAmount = totalAmount + data.Amount);
return totalAmount;
```

Answer (score 6):

From array of objects

```
function getSum(array, column)
  let values = array.map((item) => parseInt(item[column]) || 0)
  return values.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
}

foo = [
  { a: 1, b: "" },
  { a: null, b: 2 },
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
]

getSum(foo, a) == 3
getSum(foo, b) == 6
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
const sum = traveler.reduce((acc , val)=>{
   return acc + val.amount;
} ,0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one-liner using ES6 arrow functions.

```
const sumPropertyValue = (items, prop) => items.reduce((a, b) => a + b[prop], 0);

// usage:
const cart_items = [ {quantity: 3}, {quantity: 4}, {quantity: 2} ];
const cart_total = sumPropertyValue(cart_items, 'quantity');
```

Answer (score 4):

After going through these answers I think that actually a `for` (or `forEach` or `for of` with `await`) loop is much more readable that than `reduce` or even `map` and `reduce`.
Think of:

1. coming back to this code after 6 months or maintaining this by someone else. I think your approach of using a loop is good enough.
2. extending this function in the future, in case you might want to add a currency conversion or similar. Doing this in a one-liner is not a great idea.

```js
var traveler = [
  {Amount: 50,  description: 'Senior'},
  {Amount: 50,  description: 'Senior'},
  {Amount: 75,  description: 'Adult'},
  {Amount: 35,  description: 'Child'},
  {Amount: 25,  description: 'Infant'}
];

var sumFromArray = (propertyName, array) => {
  let sum = 0;
  array.forEach(item => {
    sum += item[propertyName] ?? 0;
  });
  return sum;
};

var sumOfTraveler = sumFromArray('Amount', traveler);
console.log(sumOfTraveler);
```

Using types your function definition might look like:

```
const sumFromArray = (propertyName: string, array: Array<{[propertyName: string]: number}>) => { ... };
```

See here for more details: [TypeScript A computed property name in a type literal must directly refer to a built-in symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110641/typescript-a-computed-property-name-in-a-type-literal-must-directly-refer-to-a-b)

I have nothing against `map`, `reduce` or one-liners, this is just food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

How to sum array of object using Javascript

```
const traveler = [
  {  description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
  {  description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
  {  description: 'Adult', Amount: 75},
  {  description: 'Child', Amount: 35},
  {  description: 'Infant', Amount: 25 }
];
```

```js
const traveler = [
    {  description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
    {  description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
    {  description: 'Adult', Amount: 75},
    {  description: 'Child', Amount: 35},
    {  description: 'Infant', Amount: 25 },
];
function sum(arrayData, key){
   return arrayData.reduce((a,b) => {
  return {Amount : a.Amount + b.Amount}
})
}
console.log(sum(traveler))
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I find more flexible:

```
function sumOfArrayWithParameter (array, parameter) {
  let sum = null;
  if (array && array.length > 0 && typeof parameter === 'string') {
    sum = 0;
    for (let e of array) if (e && e.hasOwnProperty(parameter)) sum += e[parameter];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

To get the sum, simply use it like that:

```
let sum = sumOfArrayWithParameter(someArray, 'someProperty');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was already using jquery. But I think its intuitive enough to just have:

```
var total_amount = 0; 
$.each(traveler, function( i, v ) { total_amount += v.Amount ; });
```

This is basically just a short-hand version of @akhouri's answer.

Answer (score 0):

i honestly got frustrated while reading all the code that where posted as a solution to this cus i'm a new be and i'n trying to add a functionality to a simple app for practice. The simple way to solve this is

```
let testArray = [5, 7, 8, 4];

function(){
sum = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++){
    sum += testArray[i];
}
```

// will give you the sum of the array

Comment: Its old but it works guys. Why all the downvotes? I know most modern JS devs would reject this but is there a performance (one that has actually been measured) reason to reject this? I wouldn't use it professionally because of peer pressure from the team and if the team doesn't want it then its fine. But for a personally project, if there is no performance penalty then its fine. Its just code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jscollection library for database like query job easily in just one line
https://github.com/somnathpanja/jscollection

```
var total = List.extend(traveler).select('Amount').sum();
```