# Sum of string values on array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reactjs, sum

I need to sum some object values in an array. Some can be `int` while others can be `string` ie:

**JavaScript:**

```
let array = [
 {quantity: 1, amount: "24.99"}
 {quantity: 5, amount: "4.99"},
]
```

Digging around Stack Overflow I have found [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247859/better-way-to-sum-a-property-value-in-an-array-using-angularjs) (Im using React):

```
Array.prototype.sum = function (prop) {
    var total = 0
    for ( var i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++ ) {
        total += this[i][prop]
    }
    return total
};

let totalQuantity = array.sum("quantity");
console.log(totalQuantity);
```

While that works great, I need to do the same for the string `amount`. Since I need to convert `amount` into float, the above will not work. React complains about `Component's children should not be mutated.`

Not being JS ninja, I thought this would do some magic:

```
Array.prototype.sum = function (prop) {
    var newProp = parseFloat(prop);
    var total = 0
    for ( var i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++ ) {
        total += this[i][newProp] // Surely this is wrong :(
    }
    return total
};
```

Any clean way to achieve this?

I need this:

```
let totalAmount = array.sum("amount");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a generic `sum` function, which is as trivial as

```
let sum = a => a.reduce((x, y) => x + y);
```

and apply it to the list of values picked from the source array:

```js
let array = [
 {quantity: 1, amount: "24.99"},
 {quantity: 5, amount: "4.99"}
];
  
let sum = a => a.reduce((x, y) => x + y);
  
let totalAmount = sum(array.map(x => Number(x.amount)));
  
console.log(totalAmount.toFixed(2))
```

Comment: Good catch. I was wondering if there's another way instead of using `Array.prototype`

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
Array.prototype.sum = function (prop) {
    var total = 0
    for ( var i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++ ) {
        total += parseFloat(this[i][prop]) // Surely this will work :)
    }
    return total
};
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhh! Thanks for that. It's good to have another eye to look at things.

Comment: @Sylar take a look to the array.reduce version ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
 {quantity: 1, amount: "24.99"},
 {quantity: 5, amount: "4.99"}
]
  
Array.prototype.sum = function(key) {
  return this.reduce(function(total, item) {
    return total + parseFloat(item[key]);
  }, 0);
}

// weird javascript math ...
console.log(array.sum("amount"));

// workaround
console.log(array.sum("amount").toFixed(2));
```

This work fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the `reduce()` method for situations like these. Here is a little demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/zKEQgL

```
let array = [
 {quantity: 1, amount: "24.99"},
 {quantity: 5, amount: "4.99"}
]

function sumProperty(arr, type) {
  return arr.reduce((total, obj) => {
    if (typeof obj[type] === 'string') {
      return total + Number(obj[type]);
    }
    return total + obj[type];
  }, 0);
}

let totalAmount = ( sumProperty(array, 'amount') ).toFixed(2); 
console.log(  totalAmount  ); // 29.98

let totalQuantity = sumProperty(array, 'quantity'); 
console.log(  totalQuantity  ); // 6
```