# TypeScript A computed property name in a type literal must directly refer to a built-in symbol

Tags: typescript

> ERROR in ...component.ts (..,..): A computed property name in a type
>   literal must directly refer to a built- in symbol. ...: Cannot find
>   name 'any'.

I'm looking forward an object which contains strings which have other string, i.e:

```
{ abc: 'xyz' }
```

What I did:

```
foo: { [string]: string };
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

An identifying name on the computed value is required:

```
foo: { [bar: string]: string };
```

Comment: Just a note that if your key type comes from a generic, you'll need to use a different solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65996861/10246801

Answer (score 46):

I had a similar issue after building. The two issues I faced were with using numbers and or enum values as keys in objects. Just to help those that see this in the future.

## Enums as keys

```
export enum MyEnum {
  one = 'stringOne',
  two = 'stringTwo',
}

export const someMap = {
  [ MyEnum.one ]: 'valueOne',
  [ MyEnum.two ]: 'valueTwo',
};
```

This will transpile `someMap` to a type that look something like...

```
export declare const someMap: {
  [ MyEnum.one ]: string;
  [ MyEnum.two ]: string;
};
```

Note the keys are still the enum value and not strings, typescript/angular does not like that because it is expecting something like...

```
export declare const someMap: {
  [ x: string ]: string;
};
```

So two possible fixes are...

#### 1) Assign explicit type to `someMap`

```
export interface ForceStringType {
  [product: string]: string;
}
export const someMap: ForceStringType = {
  [ MyEnum.one ]: 'valueOne',
  [ MyEnum.two ]: 'valueTwo',
};
```

#### 2) Assign `string` type to keys of `someMap`

```
export const someMap: ForceStringType = {
  [ MyEnum.one as string ]: 'valueOne',
  [ MyEnum.two as string ]: 'valueTwo',
};
```

## Numbers as keys

```
const CONSTANT_ONE = 123;
const CONSTANT_TWO = 321;

export const someMap = {
  [ CONSTANT_ONE ]: 'valueOne',
  [ CONSTANT_TWO ]: 'valueTwo',
};
```

This will transpile `someMap` to a type that look something like...

```
export declare const someMap: {
  [ CONSTANT_ONE ]: string;
  [ CONSTANT_TWO ]: string;
};
```

Note the keys are still the constant/number value and not strings, typescript/angular is again expecting something like...

```
export declare const someMap: {
  [ x: string ]: string;
};
```

So one possible fix is...

#### Interpolate number as string for each key of `someMap`

```
export declare const someMap: {
  [ `${CONSTANT_ONE}` ]: string;
  [ `${CONSTANT_TWO}` ]: string;
};
```

> Note: Accessing a value from `someMap` with the constant/number as a key should not matter as typescript will coerce it to a string anyway, but probably best for overall consistency.
>
> ```
> const valueOne: string = someMap[ CONSTANT_ONE ];
> // vs
> const valueOne: string = someMap[ `${CONSTANT_ONE}` ];
> ```

Answer (score 33):

The [currently accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44110642) answer will not work if the key type comes from a generic. For that to work, you need to use the `in` operator:

```
type WithKey<K extends string | number | symbol> = {
    [k in K]: boolean
}
```

[Credit here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29259#issuecomment-451458422).

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue in a Vue component, my problem was that I was incorrectly binding class names:

[Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes)

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    className: String,
  },

  setup() {
    const isModified = computed<boolean>(() => true)

    return {
      isModified,
    }

<template>
  <!-- BAD -->
  <div 
    class="static-class" 
    :class="{ [className]: true, 'static-class--modified': isModified }]">
  </div>

  <!-- GOOD -->
  <div 
    class="static-class" 
    :class="[className, { 'static-class--modified': isModified }]">
  </div>
</template>
```