# TypeScript - A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to use the computer property name feature in my typescript code as

```
import {camelCase} from "lodash";

const camelizeKeys = (obj:any):any => {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj.map(v => camelizeKeys(v));
  } else if (obj !== null && obj.constructor === Object) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(
      (result, key) => ({
        ...result,
        [camelCase(key)]: camelizeKeys(obj[key]),   // error on [camelCase(key)]
      }),
      {},
    );
  }
  return obj;
};
```

It's giving a compile time error as:

> A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.ts

I tried to resolve this error by following [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110641/typescript-a-computed-property-name-in-a-type-literal-must-directly-refer-to-a-b), but no success.

Comment: how did you implement `camelCase()`?

Comment: Probably `camelCase` does not return `string` or `number` ?

Comment: @Thomas, I updated the question, camelCase is a lodash function

Comment: you may have to add type hints for `camelCase` so TS knows that it returns a string?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the lodash typings?

```
npm install @types/lodash
```

If so and they still don't work, you may just have to assert the type of `camelCase(key)`:

```
[camelCase(key):string]: camelizeKeys(obj[key]),
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer by @Klaycon. I installed the types, which give me a hint for the return type of camelCase(). Then I managed to solve the problem as

```
 [String(camelCase(key))]: camelizeKeys(obj[key]),
```