# How to get a field value from an array and add the values using Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like below.

```
[{"rowid":1,"amount":5000,"checked":true},
{"rowid":2,"amount":1500,"checked":true},
{"rowid":3,"amount":500,"checked":true}]
```

where I have 3 rows and in each row I have a field called  **amount**. I want to add the value of all **amount fields** so that I will get result **7000**.

Comment: TypeScript is just JavaScript with type annotations. It offers no new features to handle a problem like this. By the way, this is not a "Jsonarray", It's an "array". With regard to your problem itself, is there some problem with the approach of looping over the array elements and adding up the `amount` property of each one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to sum a property value in an array (Using Angularjs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247859/better-way-to-sum-a-property-value-in-an-array-using-angularjs)

Comment: @ torazaburo .I donot know javascript also. and i  want the solution using typescript

Comment: @ torazaburo  Yes i want the same functionality like this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247859/better-way-to-sum-a-property-value-in-an-array-using-angularjs.
Can you please tell me how to acheive the same using Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract `amount` use `.map` and to add items `.reduce`

```
let arraylist = [{"rowid":1,"amount":5000,"checked":true}
                 {"rowid":2,"amount":1500,"checked":true},
                 {"rowid":3,"amount":500,"checked":true}];
const bArray = arraylist.map(({ amount }) => amount);
const result = bArray.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
console.log(result);     // output = 7000
```