# Sum two values in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If I have a javascript object like this:

```
sampleObject[
   {
    suite: "Clubs",
    weight : 10
   },
   {
    suite: "Spades",
    weight : 6
   },
   {
    suite: "Hearts",
    weight : 2
   }
];
```

How would I go about finding the sum of the weight properties?

Comment: var sum=0;
sampleObject.forEach(function(obj){
   sum += obj.weight;
});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to sum a property value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247859/better-way-to-sum-a-property-value-in-an-array)

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: `data.reduce((r, {weight}) => r + weight, 0)`

Comment: Rare occurrence of most people homing in on the same colour for the [bike-shed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality)  here…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple sum reduction should work.

`var sum = sampleObject.reduce(( sum, card ) => sum + card.weight, 0 );`

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about this last parameter for the reduce method.

Comment: The second one is the initial value. This makes the function work on arrays of length 1, which would fail if you don't use the initial value. It's also handy to use a complex accumulator this way without the need for boilerplate checking that.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I initially tried a reduce function but my parameters were set to (a,b). I didn't know you can add properties to parameters, thank you again

Answer (score 3):

You can `map` your object then `reduce` it:

1. `samplObject` => `[weight0, weight1, weight2]`
2. `[weight0, weight1, weight2]` => `weight0 + weight1 + weight2`

This means you transform your initial list into a list of weights, then you sum the values one by one.

```
const sampleObject = [
  {
    suite: "Clubs",
    weight : 10
  },
  {
    suite: "Spades",
    weight : 6
  },
  {
    suite: "Hearts",
    weight : 2
  }
];

let sum = sampleObject.map( el=> el.weight).reduce( (a,b) => a+b);
console.log(sum)
```

Output :

```
18
```

**Note :**

In this particular example, `map` is an overhead. You can calculate the sum easily :

```
let sum = sampleObject.reduce( (a,b) => a+b.weight,0);
```

**But** for more complex data structures, and in general, it's nice to have the concept of `map-reduce` in mind.

Comment: why `map`? Just overhead.

Comment: Yes, it's overhead in this minimal example. But If OP has a more complex structure, like nested objects it would be nice to have a general concept like `map-reduce` in mind.

Comment: Then maybe make a better example/description. Just a hint. In the current example it's unnecessary.

Comment: Still don't get it. What do you mean by complex? Even if the value to sum up is somwhere else or deeper located, you could use just `reduce`. For Example `weight: [{value: 10}]` just need to change the reduce operation to `a + b.weight[0].value`. So I would be really interested in an examples whenever `map` is useful here.

Answer (score 2):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method and pass a initial value as `0`.You can also use normal for loop or `forEach` method

```js
let sampleObject = [{
    suite: "Clubs",
    weight: 10
  },
  {
    suite: "Spades",
    weight: 6
  },
  {
    suite: "Hearts",
    weight: 2
  }
];

let sum = sampleObject.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  //Initially the value of acc will be 0
 // curr is the current object in context
  acc += curr.weight
   return acc;
}, 0)
console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
sampleObject = [
   {
    suite: "Clubs",
    weight : 10
   },
   {
    suite: "Spades",
    weight : 6
   },
   {
    suite: "Hearts",
    weight : 2
   }
];

var sum = sampleObject.reduce((a, b) => a + b.weight, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an array of objects, you can access the first 'weight' variable by doing: `sampleObject[0].weight`. With that considered, you can sum all of them with a simple for loop:

```
var sum = 0

for(var i = 0; i < sampleObject.length; i+){
  sum += sampleObject[i].weight
} 
console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce`:

```js
let sampleObject = [{
  suite: "Clubs",
  weight : 10
}, {
  suite: "Spades",
  weight : 6
}, {
  suite: "Hearts",
  weight : 2
}];

let sum = sampleObject.reduce((a, b) => a + b.weight, 0);
console.log(sum);
```