# Whats the best way to get the total from the cart?

Tags: javascript, json

I currently have the cart stored like this:

```
[ { itemid: '572462', name: 'item1', amount: '1', price: '499' },
  { itemid: '572458', name: 'Item2', amount: '1', price: '699' } ]
```

Whats the best way to loop through the cart and get the total price with amount * price? I cant quite figure it out...

Current code:

```
var total;
for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
  total += cart[i].price * cart[i].amount;
}
console.log(total);
```

this console.log always give me a NaN

Comment: What have you tried? Information about how to loop through an array is quite readily available.

Comment: Show us the code you are using so we can help out.

Comment: Well I know, but everything I tried already didn't work... I'll add my current loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to sum a property value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247859/better-way-to-sum-a-property-value-in-an-array)

Comment: The problem with your code is that `total` is not initialized and has an initial value of `undefined`. In JavaScript, `undefined` plus a number is NaN (and NaN plus a number is NaN). Initialize the variable to zero and your loop should work. But as the answers below state, it's cleaner to use `.reduce()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt is close, but doesn't work because your `price` and `amount` values are *strings* (that is, they're encased in quotes). Now, if you had instantiated your `total` variable to `0`, the code would then realize you want `price` and `amount` to be added *as a number*, and work as you expect:

```js
var cart = [ { itemid: '572462', name: 'item1', amount: '1', price: '499' },
  { itemid: '572458', name: 'Item2', amount: '1', price: '699' } ];

var total = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
  total += cart[i].price * cart[i].amount;
}
console.log(total);
```

---

Personally, I prefer to use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to do this sort of thing.

```js
var items = [ { itemid: '572462', name: 'item1', amount: '1', price: '499' },
  { itemid: '572458', name: 'Item2', amount: '1', price: '699' } ]
  
var total = items.reduce((total, item) => total + (+item.price * +item.amount), 0);

console.log(total);
```

`.reduce()` works by looping through each item within an array and modifying an "accumulator". The accumulator is the value that will eventually be returned. For example, if you were trying to sum the items of an array, you'd do `accummulator + currentItem`. At the end, your accumulator would be the sum of all the numbers.

Note that I've prefixed your `item.price` and `item.amount` with a unary `+` operator, so that string values (`"699"`) would instead be converted to integers (`699`) before combining them.

Comment: wow, thank you, looks like it works now... What exactly is this "accumulator"?

Comment: I've edited to hopefully provide a bit of clarity. The `accumulator` in this case is the total of all the items in the array. As we loop through the array, we add `item.price * item.amount` to the accumulator. The `, 0` at the very end tells the function to start our accumulator at `0`.

Comment: perfect, I think I understand now how this works, thank you very much!

Comment: "*if you were trying to add every item in an array, you'd do `accummulator + currentItem`*" wouldn't you rather use `accummulator.push(currentItem)`?

Comment: @Luca - It was a poor choice of words on my part. I didn't mean add every item **to** an array, but rather "add-up" the numbers within one. The obviously better way to explain this would have been *"if you were trying to sum the items of an array"*. I've edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

[With Array.reduce():](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
const cartTotal = cart.reduce((total, item) => {
  return total + (Number(item.price) * Number(item.amount));
}, 0);
```

Comment: hm looks like a good solution, but it cartTotal is 0449699 then...

Comment: Values need coerced from strings to numbers. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Iterate through the array
2. Each iteration:

   - get the amount value, convert to integer
   - get the price value, convert to integer
   - Multiply these two
   - Add to a running total variable

When done, your running total variable has the total.

```
var total;
for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
  total += parseInt(cart[i].price) * parseInt(cart[i].amount);
}
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

just iterate through it and calc

```
 var total_price= 0;
var cart_list = [ { itemid: '572462', name: 'item1', amount: '1', price: '499' },
  { itemid: '572458', name: 'Item2', amount: '1', price: '699' } ];

cart_list.forEach(function(obj){
    total_price+= obj.amount*obj.price;
});
console.log(total_price) //this is the total price
```