# sum of items in a multidimensional array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, sum

I have the following array:

```js
const response = [{
    name: "ISA Portfolio",
    value: 0,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "ISA Cash",
    value: 0,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Bank 1 Year Fixed",
    value: 149058.15234375,
    count: 2
  },
  {
    name: "1 Year Fixed",
    value: 167488.0546875,
    count: 2
  },
  {
    name: "t Bank 1 Year Fixed",
    value: 250223.4375,
    count: 3
  },
  {
    name: "M Bank 1 Year Fixed Term",
    value: 149222.48828125,
    count: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Jr",
    value: 768930.5625,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "I Income Bond",
    value: 400486.1875,
    count: 3
  },
  {
    name: "In 1 Year Fixed",
    value: 83620.2734375,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "I 3 Year Guaranteed Income Bond",
    value: 140000,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "I 1 Year Guaranteed Growth Bond",
    value: 600000,
    count: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Co",
    value: 46382.26171875,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Management",
    value: 1113677,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Cs & Co",
    value: 973906,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "C Fund",
    value: 82389.640625,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "I 3 Year Guaranteed Growth Bond",
    value: 250000,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "S Saver",
    value: 85194.953125,
    count: 1
  }
]


const sum = response.reduce(function(a, b) {
  (a[b.value] ? a[b.value] += b.value : a[b.value] = b.value);
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(sum);
```

but this returns the value only in an object and not the sum. Can you please help. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to sum a property value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247859/better-way-to-sum-a-property-value-in-an-array)

Comment: FYI, that's an array of objects, not a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just map over the `.value` property first and reduce it later:**

```js
const response = [{
    name: "ISA Portfolio",
    value: 0,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "ISA Cash",
    value: 0,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Bank 1 Year Fixed",
    value: 149058.15234375,
    count: 2
  },
  {
    name: "1 Year Fixed",
    value: 167488.0546875,
    count: 2
  },
  {
    name: "t Bank 1 Year Fixed",
    value: 250223.4375,
    count: 3
  },
  {
    name: "M Bank 1 Year Fixed Term",
    value: 149222.48828125,
    count: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Jr",
    value: 768930.5625,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "I Income Bond",
    value: 400486.1875,
    count: 3
  },
  {
    name: "In 1 Year Fixed",
    value: 83620.2734375,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "I 3 Year Guaranteed Income Bond",
    value: 140000,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "I 1 Year Guaranteed Growth Bond",
    value: 600000,
    count: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Co",
    value: 46382.26171875,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Management",
    value: 1113677,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Cs & Co",
    value: 973906,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "C Fund",
    value: 82389.640625,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "I 3 Year Guaranteed Growth Bond",
    value: 250000,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "S Saver",
    value: 85194.953125,
    count: 1
  }
]


const sum = response.map(x => x.value).reduce((a, b) => a + b);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: bingo that worked, not sure why I can't accept as an answer. I will try later