# How to put numbers together with a specific field in array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of Objects and I would like to put numbers together in a specific field in those Objects.
The Age field in each object.

this is what I did :

```
var users = [{name:'John',age:36},{name:'Max',age:21}]


var counter = 0;
var example = users.forEach(function(user){
counter += user.age
})
```

Comment: ok, so what is the issue?

Comment: could you add a sample of the array containing the user data so we can create code snippets to create working examples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to sum a property value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247859/better-way-to-sum-a-property-value-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple `for` loop:

```
var users = [
  {
    age: 22
  },
  {
    age: 25
  },
  {
    age: 70
  }
];

var ageSum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  ageSum += users[i].age;
}

console.log(ageSum);
```

Comment: You can use array.reduce() to do it in an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` like that

```
let sum = users.reduce((a,b) => a.age + b.age, 0);
```