# get sum of a specific key in javascript object

Tags: javascript

I want to get the sum of all `menge` keys in my js object and store it inside a variable. Can someone help me out on how to do this? Snippet of my object:

```
var obj = {
  "_15800175": {
    "posID": "159469",
    "scanID": "22597",
    "anr": "15800175",
    "TVanr": "",
    "code": "G-09-27-2E",
    "ean": "4710069680575",
    "marke": "fox",
    "bez": "jersey yellow",
    "bez2": "size xl",
    "menge": "1",
    "ve": "St\u00fcck",
    "Dimensionstext": "TT9857BG\r\n",
    "Langtext": ""
  },
  "_15100027": {
    "posID": "159471",
    "scanID": "22597",
    "anr": "15100027",
    "TVanr": "",
    "code": "G-11-03-2A",
    "ean": "4712511825411",
    "marke": "fox",
    "bez2": "jersey L",
    "menge": "1",
    "ve": "St\u00fcck",
    "Dimensionstext": "blue\r\n",
    "Langtext": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to sum a property value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247859/better-way-to-sum-a-property-value-in-an-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Object.values()` and `Array.reduce()` like following:

```js
var obj = {
  "_15800175": {
    "posID": "159469",
    "scanID": "22597",
    "anr": "15800175",
    "TVanr": "",
    "code": "G-09-27-2E",
    "ean": "4710069680575",
    "marke": "fox",
    "bez": "jersey yellow",
    "bez2": "size xl",
    "menge": "1",
    "ve": "St\u00fcck",
    "Dimensionstext": "TT9857BG\r\n",
    "Langtext": ""
  },
  "_15100027": {
    "posID": "159471",
    "scanID": "22597",
    "anr": "15100027",
    "TVanr": "",
    "code": "G-11-03-2A",
    "ean": "4712511825411",
    "marke": "fox",
    "bez2": "jersey L",
    "menge": "1",
    "ve": "St\u00fcck",
    "Dimensionstext": "blue\r\n",
    "Langtext": ""
  },
  "dummy": {
    "menge": "not-convertable-to-integer"
  },
   "dummy2": {
    // This item does NOT have "menge" property
  }
}

var sumMenge = Object.values(obj).reduce((sum, item) => sum + (!isNaN(+item.menge) || 0),0);
//                                                                    ^^^ This is to convert item.menge to number

console.log(sumMenge);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: or without parenthesis: `Object.values(obj).reduce((sum, item)=>+item.menge + sum,0)`

Comment: One side effect of this is that it'll return NaN is the `menge` property is missing or otherwise can't be converted to a number. May or may not be intended behavior.

Comment: @Scribblemacher I updated the answer by adding a non-convertable value and a `isNaN` check.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is iterate on the keys of the main object and then reduce it to the sum ie:
`Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => acc = obj[key].menge + acc, 0)`

Comment: I think you should swap `key, acc` arguments as the first argument of `reduce` is accumulator. And `menge` is string so you need to convert it to number first.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.reduce()` after getting the keys array

```js
var obj = {
      "_15800175": {
          "posID": "159469",
          "scanID": "22597",
          "anr": "15800175",
          "TVanr": "",
          "code": "G-09-27-2E",
          "ean": "4710069680575",
          "marke": "fox",
          "bez": "jersey yellow",
          "bez2": "size xl",
          "menge": "1",
          "ve": "St\u00fcck",
          "Dimensionstext": "TT9857BG\r\n",
          "Langtext": ""
      },
      "_15100027": {
          "posID": "159471",
          "scanID": "22597",
          "anr": "15100027",
          "TVanr": "",
          "code": "G-11-03-2A",
          "ean": "4712511825411",
          "marke": "fox",
          "bez2": "jersey L",
          "menge": "1",
          "ve": "St\u00fcck",
          "Dimensionstext": "blue\r\n",
          "Langtext": ""
      }
  }

  var menge_sum = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(old, cur) {
      old += Number(obj[cur]['menge'])
      return old
  }, 0);
  console.log(menge_sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the object keys into a array.

```
var id=Object.keys(obj); //get all keys
var menge=0;// init...
for (i=0;i<id.length;i++){// run over all keys found
  menge=menge+obj[id[i]].menge; /add the things
}
console.log(menge);//see result
```

see [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through object's properties names using `for (prop in obj)`. Then you can simply use `total += +obj[prop].menge || 0;`. Here `+obj[prop].menge` will convert into `number`. `+obj[prop].menge || 0;` this line will be return `0` if object does not contain `menge` property.

```js
var obj = {
  "_15800175": {
    "posID": "159469",
    "scanID": "22597",
    "anr": "15800175",
    "TVanr": "",
    "code": "G-09-27-2E",
    "ean": "4710069680575",
    "marke": "fox",
    "bez": "jersey yellow",
    "bez2": "size xl",
    "menge": "1",
    "ve": "St\u00fcck",
    "Dimensionstext": "TT9857BG\r\n",
    "Langtext": ""
  },
  "_15100027": {
    "posID": "159471",
    "scanID": "22597",
    "anr": "15100027",
    "TVanr": "",
    "code": "G-11-03-2A",
    "ean": "4712511825411",
    "marke": "fox",
    "bez2": "jersey L",
    "menge": "1",
    "ve": "St\u00fcck",
    "Dimensionstext": "blue\r\n",
    "Langtext": ""
  }
}

let total = 0;
for (prop in obj) { 
  total += +obj[prop].menge || 0;
}

console.log(total);
```