# How can I get a total when iterate an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, react-native

I got an array of an object from the Database and inside every object.

I have a **price** and **count** I need to get every item price and after that should I calculate the total price of all items and set it into state.

Here's structure array I got from DB:

```
state = {
  TotalCountTools: null, // here will get all the total price for every item
  toolsUsed: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'tool 1',
        price: 10,
        count: 3,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'tool 2',
        price: 5,
        count: 3,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'tool 3',
        price: 1,
        count: 2,
      },
    ],
}
```

Here's what I tried and it's failed:

```
renderToolsUsed = () => {
    let {TotalCountTools} = this.state;
    return this.state.toolsUsed.map(({name, id, price, count}, i) => {
      let TotalCount = count * price;
      console.log(TotalCount);
      this.setState({TotalCountTools: TotalCount}, () =>
        console.log(TotalCountTools), // so in every iterate that will set a state and that's wrong i know 
      );

      return (
        <>
          <View>
            <Text key={id}>{name}</Text>
          </View>

          <View>
            <Text key={id}>{price}</Text>
          </View>

          <View>
            <Text key={id}>{count}</Text>
          </View>
       </>
      );
    });
  };
```

**EDIT**

after I see all answers I just follow as @Shubh says to get total price
so i make another function just to get the total price

```
 getTotalPrice = () => {
    let total = this.state.toolsUsed.reduce((acc, {price, count}) => {
      acc = acc + price * count;
      return acc;
    }, 0);
    this.setState({totalPriceTools: total}, () =>
      console.log(this.state.totalPriceTools),
    );
  };
```

and inside a UI i added it

```
 render() {
  return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
         {this.renderToolsUsed()}
   <>
              <Text
                style={{
                  paddingBottom: 5,
                  fontWeight: '700',
                  fontSize: 17,
                  color: '#9F9F9F',
                  marginLeft: 20,
                }}>
               Total Price:
              </Text>
              {this.getTotalPrice()} // I don't know how can i call this function so i added it here and that's wrong insted of it should i write {this.state.totalPriceTools}
            </>
 )
}
```

UI

"I add a flag in the state after getting a total price I want to update it and used it in other View"
[image: UI]

**EDIT 2**

I want after render the tools item "map finish" invoke other function "calculate the total prices"

```
  renderToolsUsed = () => {
    const {toolsUsed} = this.state;
    const prom = toolsUsed.map(({name, id, price, count}) => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.tools}>
          <View style={styles.toolsItem}>
            <Text key={id}>{name}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.toolsItem}>
            <Text key={id}>{price}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.toolsItem}>
            <Text key={id}>{count}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    });
    return Promise.all(prom).then(() => this.getTotalPrice());
  };


  getTotalPrice = () => {
    let total = this.state.toolsUsed.reduce((acc, {price, count}) => {
      acc = acc + price * count;
      return acc;
    }, 0);
    this.setState({totalPriceTools: total}, () =>
      console.log(this.state.totalPriceTools),
    );
  };
```

I got this error

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as
>   a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to sum a property value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247859/better-way-to-sum-a-property-value-in-an-array)

Comment: Try using `toolsUsed.reduce`. It'll let you accumulate a value.

Comment: Can you please share the interface, defining the state?

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider check the question again! that's enough?

Comment: RE: your first edit, just create an other view/component 'View2' with a prop 'total' and in that component's render() method put a span i.e. <span>this.props.total</span>. Then in parent component, call 'getTotalPrice()' in ComponentDidMount() and in it's render() method add View2 as <View2 total={this.state.totalPriceTools}></View2>. you'll get it working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for the job;

```js
let toolsUsed = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'tool 1',
    price: 10,
    count: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'tool 2',
    price: 5,
    count: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'tool 3',
    price: 1,
    count: 2,
  },
]
let total = toolsUsed.reduce((acc, {
  price,
  count
}) => {
  acc = acc + price * count;
  return acc;
}, 0)

console.log(total)
// Or particular total for element
toolsUsed.forEach(ele => {
  ele["total"] = ele.price * ele.count;
})
console.log(toolsUsed)
```

Comment: But how can i render the ui ? or make other functions for it? and when i set a state i will get an error `Maximum update depth exceeded`

Comment: Well  Just change the map and use the function I stated.

Comment: I try but i got the same error when i `setState({totalPriceTool total)`

Answer (score 1):

As I understand this is what you are searching for

```js
const tools = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'tool 1',
    price: 10,
    count: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'tool 2',
    price: 5,
    count: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'tool 3',
    price: 1,
    count: 2,
  },
]

const result = {};
tools.forEach((tool) => {
  result[tool.id] = tool.price * tool.count;
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Can u check the question again i add some image details

Answer (score 0):

What i have understood is: you want to calculate total price for every item i.e. price*count, in the array and then sum all calculated prices and set the state. If it is so then you can create a function lets say '`CalculateEachOrderPrice()`' in which you will iterate through the array and calculate total amount for each item and simply push the calculated value in an array e.g. `prices []`. After array is iterated (loop ends), calculate the sum for `prices` array and set the state. Call `CalculateEachOrderPrice()` function on `ComponentDidMount()` or success callback of the method that is returning you the object from database.

Comment: That's exactly what i want, i will try it, now can i call a `CalculateEachOrderPrice()` after `renderToolsUsed()` "map" finish? because when a use a `Promise.all()` i got an infinite loop -_-

Comment: Point is to call the function once you have successfully retrieved the object from db and this CalculateEachOrderPrice() should return the value before component's render method is called (which generates virtual DOM)

Comment: Yeah i know that, but just a question in my mind to use a Promise

Comment: yes you may use the promise which when resolved, call the function to render the component

Comment: can u check the question again :)

Comment: Yeah but setting state in every iteration is not recommended, resulting in re-rendering the component time and again. you need to set the state once you have the sum of all prices.

Comment: can you re-edit your answer to achieve ur idea? Sorry about thats but i cant handle it

Comment: I'm waiting :"D

Comment: haha, check my comment on your question, you are on right track, go with your first edit then try following what i wrote there

Comment: I just add getTotalPrice() inside componentDidMount() and work well my question it was why i can't use Promise in this case

Comment: there was no problem with the promise but guess you were calling the function in render method right? when function got called, it used to set the state, and component is re-rendered as a result of setting the state which would have caused an infinite loop like situation

Comment: yes i call `renderToolsUsed()` in render function !