# How to search array of objects and get totals

Tags: javascript

How do I search this array of objects and return the totals of all the price attributes

```
  Data = [ {id:0,name:”lamp”,price: 5}
            {id:1, name:”bed”, price:10}
             {id:2,name: “shelf”, price 3}]

   ... It will need to return a total of 18
```

Comment: `Data.reduce((a, e) => a + e.price, 0)` should do it although surely this is a [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247859/better-way-to-sum-a-property-value-in-an-array).... Please also show an attempt at solving the problem yourself in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `Array` has the method [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) that is very often used in cases like this one.

It takes as the first parameter a function which will be called for every element in the array and a second, but optional, argument that will be the initial value.

So, in your case, you could do something like this:

```js
const sum = Data.reduce((accumulator, obj) => accumulator + obj.price, 0)
```

The first time it's called the value of `accumulator` is **0**, the next times the value of the accumulator will be the return value of the previous call of the function```

so it will work as the following:

```js
// first call
// accumulator = 0
// obj = {id:0,name:”lamp”,price: 5}
return accumulator + obj.price

// second call
// accumulator = 5
// obj = {id:1, name:”bed”, price:10}
return accumulator + obj.price

// third call
// accumulator = 15
// obj = {id:2,name: “shelf”, price 3}
return accumulator + obj.price

// now accumulator = 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Same way you would search any other array. I'm giving you the general code, because you haven't specified any language

```
sum = 0
for element in array:
    sum = sum + element['attr']
return sum
```

Comment: It is tagged [tag:javascript], and the question is a dupe regardless so it's probably best to be closed.

Comment: oh, didn't see that. but yeah, seemed like a question you can google, so I just gave him the pseudocode so he can work it out on his own if he wanted to

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is the answer you search

```js
var Data = [ {id:0,name:'lamp',price: 5},{id:1, name:'bed', price:10},{id:1, name:'shelf', price:3}];

var sum = 0;
for (var i=0; i<Data.length;i++){
  sum += Data[i].price;
  
}
console.log(sum);
```