# Sum all object items in array with dynamic property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic

**I have the following array:**

```
[
     {category: 'Category 1', 'Apr 2021' : 10, 'Mar 2021' : 20, 'Feb 2021': 5},
     {category: 'Category 2', 'Apr 2021' : 8, 'Mar 2021' : 2, 'Feb 2021': 15},
     {category: 'Category 3', 'Apr 2021' : 7, 'Mar 2021' : 1, 'Feb 2021': 5}
]
```

I would like to *add a total row with the sum of categories in the array.*

Example:

```
[
     {category: 'Category 1', 'Apr 2021' : 10, 'Mar 2021' : 20, 'Feb 2021': 5},
     {category: 'Category 2', 'Apr 2021' : 8, 'Mar 2021' : 2, 'Feb 2021': 15},
     {category: 'Category 3', 'Apr 2021' : 7, 'Mar 2021' : 1, 'Feb 2021': 5},
     {category: 'Total',      'Apr 2021' : 25, 'Mar 2021' : 23, 'Feb 2021': 30}
]
```

I tried looping through all columns using `Object.keys`. However, it feels like there may be an easier way to achieve this.

What is the best way to calculate the total row?

**Please note that "Apr 2021", "Mar 2021" are not fixed so I won't be able to hardcode them.**

Comment: Hi, would this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247859/better-way-to-sum-a-property-value-in-an-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to sum a property value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247859/better-way-to-sum-a-property-value-in-an-array)

Comment: @mertdökümcü Yes, that is the article I sent, too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Please note that "Apr 2021", "Mar 2021" are not fixed so I won't be
> able to hardcode them.**

In your case the properties are dynamic. You can try this way with 2 steps:

1. Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to loop all objects of the array
2. At each `object`, you sum the value of each properties  by iteration the `object` due to dynamic property like this

```
for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(curr)
```

```js
const array = [
     {category: 'Category 1', 'Apr 2021' : 10, 'Mar 2021' : 20, 'Feb 2021': 5},
     {category: 'Category 2', 'Apr 2021' : 8, 'Mar 2021' : 2, 'Feb 2021': 15},
     {category: 'Category 3', 'Apr 2021' : 7, 'Mar 2021' : 1, 'Feb 2021': 5}
];
const total = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(curr)){
    if (key !== 'category') {
      acc[key] ??= 0;
      acc[key] += value;
    }
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log([...array, {category: "Total", ...total}]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I've just updated dynamic code, pls take a look at it @developer

Comment: @developer I've just edited the title of the question to make it clearer. Pls check and correct it if need.

Answer (score 1):

```
const data = [
     {category: 'Category 1', 'Apr 2021' : 10, 'Mar 2021' : 20, 'Feb 2021': 5},
     {category: 'Category 2', 'Apr 2021' : 8, 'Mar 2021' : 2, 'Feb 2021': 15},
     {category: 'Category 3', 'Apr 2021' : 7, 'Mar 2021' : 1, 'Feb 2021': 5}
];
const res = data.reduce((result, item) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(item);
  keys.forEach(key => {
    if (key === 'category') { return; }
    result[key] = result[key] ? result[key] + item[key] : item[key];
  });
  return result;
}, { category: 'Total' });
data.push(res);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean declarative way:

```js
const input = [
     {category: 'Category 1', 'Apr 2021' : 10, 'Mar 2021' : 20, 'Feb 2021': 5},
     {category: 'Category 2', 'Apr 2021' : 8, 'Mar 2021' : 2, 'Feb 2021': 15},
     {category: 'Category 3', 'Apr 2021' : 7, 'Mar 2021' : 1, 'Feb 2021': 5}
]

const totalRow = input.reduce((acc, e) => {
    Object.keys(e)
      .filter(k => k !== 'category')
      .forEach(k => acc[k] ? acc[k] += e[k] : acc[k] = e[k])
    return acc
}, {category: 'Total'})

const res = [...input, totalRow]
console.log(res)
```