# Why array.sum is not a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to apply [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23247980/11241615) to add a given property of an array of objects. However, I'm getting different errors, depending on the situation:

Case 1:

```
var array = [{aaa: 123}, {aaa: 1313}];

class ArrayElements extends Array {
  sum: (key: string) => number = (key: string) => {
    return this.reduce((a, b) => a + (b[key] || 0), 0);
  };
}

const value = (array as ArrayElements).sum("aaa");
console.log(value);
```

In that case I get the execution error `array.sum is not a function`.

I thought that's because I didn't follow exactly the same way to create the object. However, if I do

Case 2:

```
const values = new ArrayElements(...[{aaa: 123}, {aaa: 1313}]);
```

then I get a compilation error `Argument of type '{ aaa: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.`.

I am using `TypeScript`, not plain `JavaScript`, but I guess that shouldn't be the problem...?

Comment: `as` doesn't actually cast the value. It just tells the type checker what it should assume the value is.

Comment: Type *assertions* (when you use `as`) are not type *castings*. They don't change the object, they just tell the compiler to treat it *as if* it was a different object. If I hand you a piece of cake tell you it's tea, it won't suddenly become liquid.

Comment: Ok, I see it, of course. O_O Thank you very much for the answers, I spent 2 hours looking for the error. Now I just need to know how to do the actual cast... :-D Any easy way or I have to do an ugly map?

Comment: @VLAZ tempting everyone with dessert-based analogies again, I see.

Comment: @Andy I food is the first thing that came to mind. I'm a bit ill and undernourished, so I apologise.

Comment: @VLAZ hope you feel better soon.

Comment: @xavier `ArrayElements.from(array)`, perhaps.

Comment: @VLAZ thank you for the answer. Sadly it doesn't work: `Property 'sum' does not exist on type '{ aaa: number; }[]'.`. arggggggg :-(

Comment: Case 2 works in deno. No typing errors there. Maybe make the type of array you are extending from more specific like

class ArrayElements extends Array<{[key: string]: number}> {}

Answer (score 0):

VLAZ suggested using `ArrayElements.from()`, which should work at runtime:

> In ES2015, the class syntax allows sub-classing of both built-in and user-defined classes. As a result, static methods such as `Array.from()` are "inherited" by subclasses of `Array`, and create new instances of the subclass, not `Array`.

<sup>Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)</sup>

However, [TypeScript's type system has no way to express this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), so the typings of `Array.from()` are set to return `T[]` instead of a specific subclass.

You could work around this by overriding the `from` static method:

```
class ArrayElements<T> extends Array<T> {
  static from<T>(iterable: Iterable<T> | ArrayLike<T>): ArrayElements<T>
  static from<T, U>(
    iterable: Iterable<T> | ArrayLike<T>,
    mapFn: (v: T, k: number) => U,
    thisArg?: unknown
  ): ArrayElements<U>
  static from<T, U = T>(
    ...args: [
      Iterable<T> | ArrayLike<T>,
      ((v: T, k: number) => U)?,
      unknown?
    ]
  ): ArrayElements<U> {
    return super.from(...args as Parameters<typeof Array.from>) as ArrayElements<U>;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a type assertion for the class constructor to avoid adding something at runtime:

```
class _ArrayElements<T> extends Array<T> {
  // ...
}
type ArrayElements<T> = _ArrayElements<T>
const ArrayElements = _ArrayElements as unknown as Omit<typeof _ArrayElements, 'from'> & {
  from<T>(iterable: Iterable<T> | ArrayLike<T>): ArrayElements<T>
  from<T, U>(
    iterable: Iterable<T> | ArrayLike<T>,
    mapFn: (v: T, k: number) => U,
    thisArg?: unknown
  ): ArrayElements<U>
}
```

---

Also, here's a way to type `sum` safely:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520829/8289918
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T]

class ArrayElements<T> extends Array<T> {
  // The T extends object ? ... : never prevents this being called
  // for ArrayElements of primitives
  sum(key: T extends object ? KeysMatching<T, number | undefined> : never): number {
    return this.reduce((a, b) => a + (b[key] as unknown as number | undefined || 0), 0);
  }
}

// errors
ArrayElements.from(['']).sum() // string is not an object
ArrayElements.from([{a: ''}]).sum('a') // value of a is not number
// ok
ArrayElements.from(array).sum('aaa')
```

---

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAnjAvDA2gbzvgLhgEYAmAZgF8AaGPQk84qgXQG4AoDqFABwFMYAaX4oIAWThRgACwCWYAOYAeACq0AagD4MdLEJgKYAa1EgAZjFUsiq-Sxj8AHlH5gAJhBgaYAfmEwRGD8AG78CJRYpigWVixcwAA2cBBeAIJIqACiifwAtm5QEGo6zq4e6ZkoJXQcMDDQUnLAMOYIIHklABRyrsgARrlEAJJ9cIP8NQA+MBnIKAAycqYlAJREc9m5BWBFJXUNUE0tbR1qtACqWj1jEyO3udOzVUsrqlq0eXC8AGJgRF0QrZaMYggBXPL9cKrDA6C60KDyCAZRS+IhgsDGMAgADuYHWz3mOXyhWKVwOjSgzVa7U66hgF107y6ADo2YhFBAiFhRuFxo93jAZptFstJu9aF1AcCTODIdDYQzVr5aBisbiwL4WASRcSdnsrrV6vUEPwoGCEGAGmCBAgWac8qz2QhOfAvAAFRBwAp9Yo8ASxEX22laGEpQlbEm7MlaTj1ShceoQCFdaK2RwuNyeGAgfoAK34wFg-hEYkk0nkSnOMDAEKhCCFMAx7n45gU-HcOiCoWhcvrRuNpvNlpgiLkEBZpvcYOA-ClcFo-Rh6B0cBgAGoYF1+lFRA5w2rsXi3TW6+FG83W+33EKZgAGVa0B9xmAJhMcAD0H8cSBACAgHC6tspLBh0XRYAA5BB2ossmjqrIBVR6iBDrgXgRBQZQMFwV0EFwBBCFfjmxgcKAkAgLkLKJCAihdEBUZFKBjqIPMqywSmeH4ARCGkckqQwAA+vR+oQKQNRlFmlTzDUOAUimaZWBm5TZrmBZFn4wiiBIUiyAoKj0rW8oNjMl5tsEnaBDWPYIAShn9rJxowEOFpWmOE5TjOc5dAuMBLoqa6btuu4oPuXiHhqJ52eeJkeFe5m3jAD5PqsL5vtwfCCMJpJiYKmBCUhwHRjlWikeA0ARigyFFbo+VEoVRSkCe4XHuGADyeS9Mo-r8LEtWRiJpC0BBDoQToABkA4Ot0vR8ncMC8gMAo6MKLximsGwFQxon7PUU30lcNyzUM80POKy0Va8Z2fN8fwAkCVggn2CorgyCJIiiaJNpiR74htdVbWJ5LvkR4TtP+iH-QNTHgVB2EpghWVFdDuBwBhEFYWxOF4QRn7fiAJFkRAFH8FRNF0ZtUOoSxqCYxx+D4asCFAA)