# sum all values of an object in an array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects that looks like this

```
[{value: '20'},{value: '20'},{value: '30'}]
```

I want to sum all the values in a variable
like this

```
sum = array.GetAllObjectsValues; //output: 70
```

Comment: Please include your attempt to solve this yourself.

Comment: Also, search before asking. Example using reduce [here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-get-sum-of-array-object-values).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to sum a property value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247859/better-way-to-sum-a-property-value-in-an-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to calculate the sum

```
const sum = array.reduce((acc, o) => acc + parseInt(o.value), 0)
```

Comment: i used it it gives me 0

Comment: either all values add up to 0, or the array is empty. I just assumed `array` has the 3 values you described and I used the same identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and `Number.parseInt`

> The reduce() method executes a user-supplied "reducer" callback function on each element of the array, in order, passing in the return value from the calculation on the preceding element. The final result of running the reducer across all elements of the array is a single value.

```
[{value: '20'},{value: '20'},{value: '30'}].reduce((acc, current) => acc + Number.parseInt(current.value), 0)
```

Reduce: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Number parse Int: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with jquery

```
const array = [{value: '20'},{value: '20'},{value: '30'}];
```

Inside a $.each you can iterate thru this array of objects

```
var sum = 0;//Initial value hast to be 0
$.each(array, function(key, value) {
    var number = parseFloat(value.value);//Convert to numbers with parseFloat
    sum += number;//Sum the numbers
});

console.log(sum);//Output 70
```

Edit: Or if you don't want to use jquery, this is another solution with pure js

```
var sum = 0;//Initial value hast to be 0
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) {
    var number = parseFloat(array[i].value);//Convert to numbers with parseFloat
    sum += number;//Sum the numbers
}

console.log(sum);//Output 70
```

Comment: This is why people love Python