# Hi I need to get the sum of all the hours. Any help please?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```
"tasks" : {
    "details" : [
        {
            "task" : "a",
            "hours" : 5,
            "_id" : ObjectId("6333fdc699f7cb3da66be656")
        },
        {
            "task" : "2",
            "hours" : 5,
            "_id" : ObjectId("6335ed42115208d81dffd082")
        },
        {
            "task" : "b",
            "hours" : 6,
            "_id" : ObjectId("6335ed7d115208d81dffd118")
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to get the totals of "hours" with reduce function but I cannot make it right. Someone can help with this since I'm new to javascript?

Comment: let's see your reduce function!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your attempt at using the `reduce` function, otherwise we can't help you getting it right

Comment: what you have done so far.

Comment: That closing link is wrong, it's https://stackoverflow.com/q/72408627/2813224

Comment: @zer00ne you can edit the duplicate targets with edit button in the top right

Comment: first I was using aggr. like this exports.getTotals = expressAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const query = [
    {
      $match:{}

    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$hours',
        hours: {$sum: '$tasks.details.hours'},
        totalHrs: {$sum: 1},
        
      }
    }
  ];
  const data = await MSPQuotation.aggregate(query);
  let hours = 0;
  let totalHrs = 0;
  for(const item of data){
    hours+=item.hours;
    totalHrs+=item.totalHrs;
  }
  return res.json({
    code: 200,
    data: data,
    count: data.length,hours,totalHrs,
    enums: {}
  });
})

Comment: But I need to query the totals hours. Can somehelp me how to query "hours" from mongo?

Comment: @adiga, thanks, 9 years on this site and I never noticed that. It looks like someone already edited it to point to a more appropriate duplicate post.

Comment: @zer00ne yeah, I edited that (FYI: This info is available in the [Post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73905291/timeline)). The option is only available if you have the dupe hammer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tasks =  {
    "details" : [
        {
            "task" : "a",
            "hours" : 5,
            "_id" : ObjectId("6333fdc699f7cb3da66be656")
        },
        {
            "task" : "2",
            "hours" : 5,
            "_id" : ObjectId("6335ed42115208d81dffd082")
        },
        {
            "task" : "b",
            "hours" : 6,
            "_id" : ObjectId("6335ed7d115208d81dffd118")
        }
    ]
}
const result = tasks.details.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + +cur.hours, 0);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks a lot man. how can I query the totals of hours in mongodb?

Comment: ofc you are using mongoDB, I believe they have some things call middleware hook, you can apply one for .find (or whatever you use). Another options is view this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969916/mongodb-sum-query

Comment: I cannot query hours only for some reason :/