# How to sum numbers in table angular

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table, sum, calculated-columns

I would like to sum these numbers in my table:

[image]

Do I make a filter or ngFor is needed ?
I know that the calculation does not make sense.
I tried:

```
  <th>
    <i>Sum:{{ this.invoices?.sum | number }}</i>
 </th>
```

ts:

```
 invoices: any;

  calcSum = ( invoice: any, sum:number): string => {
        if (!invoice||!sum) { 
            return '0';
        }
        return (this.invoices.sum + this.invoices.sum); 
        
    }
```

interface:

```
export interface InvoiceResponse{
    paid: boolean,
    paidAmount: number,
    client: string,
    number: number,
    total:number,
    taxTotal: number,
    sum: number,
    currencyRate: string,
    currencyRateAtIssueDate: string,
    issuedAtPlace: string,
    issuedAt: string,
    deadlineAt: string
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**ts**

```js
calcSum = this.invoices.map((i) => i.sum).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

**html**

```html
<th>
  <i>Sum:{{ calcSum  }}</i>
</th>
```

**snippet**

```js
const invoices = [{sum:1}, {sum:2}, {sum:3}];

const calcSum = invoices.map((i) => i.sum).reduce((a, b) => a + b);

console.log(calcSum);
```

further information and some examples can be found in the following article:

- [Better way to sum a property value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247859/better-way-to-sum-a-property-value-in-an-array)